# Pass REST API data back to Node command line

Tags: node.js, rest, command-line

I’m running this command: 
`NODE_ENV=production grunt babel && NODE_ENV=sandbox node dist/bin/copilot.js --mode $1`

`copilot.js` launches another JavaScript file (depending on what the mode argument is in line above); in this case it’s `copilotMonitor.js`

The short story is this ‘Monitor’ pings a REST API record, data is returned to it on if a mode needs to be restarted. The API will return something to `copilotMonitor.js` along the lines of "mode_3". 
How can I then pass this command `pkill -9 -f <mode>` back to the command line?

I know `process.argv` tells me what arguments I passed into the node application, but I’d like to pass stuff *back* to the node app, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Answer, Node Child Process!

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v4.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback
I also found this video helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9o8B3L0-d9c

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec(`pkill -9 -f ${mode}`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(`There was an error killing mode ${mode}`);
        console.error('error: ', err);
        return;
     }
     console.log('kill restart! stdout: ', mode, stdout)
     console.log('kill restart! stderr: ', mode, stderr)
});
```